# How do I identify records that have certain flags equal to 1 within a year of each other?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data on locations that include a Location ID and a set of 3 0 or 1 flags that indicate whether or not the latitude, longitude, or address of a location has changed as well as the month end in which the change occurred.

So I am looking at something like this:

```
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| LOCATIONID | XCOORDHANGE | YCOORDCHANGE | ADDRESSCHANGE | REPORTPERIOD        |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| 1          | 0           | 0            | 1             | 2010-01-31 00:00:00 |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| 2          | 1           | 1            | 1             | 2010-03-31 00:00:00 |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| 1          | 1           | 1            | 0             | 2010-08-31 00:00:00 |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

I am tasked with identifying locations that have moved.  A move is defined as either x or y coordinate changes AND an address change (sometimes locations are re-spotted and the coordinates change but the address doesn't change, and sometimes addresses are changed without subsequent coordinate changes, and I am not interested in these sites).

Identifying when all 3 flags are set to 1 is easy enough.  The issue is that address and coordinate changes don't always come through at the same time.  Location 1, for example, shows the address change in 1/31/2010 but the coordinate change in 8/31/2010.  I need to look at each record and identify if the "move" criteria is met within a year of the first change.  For location 1 in my example above I would consider it a "move" if the x and/or y coordinate changes came through up to 1 year from the address change (that is to say the criteria are met within 1 year of each other).  Another wrinkle added in is a location can move multiple times within the 4 year period I am investigating.  I am doing this for 1/31/2010 to 12/31/2014.

My first attempt was to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LOCATIONID ORDER BY REPORTPERIOD ASC) as rn` and use a self-join on `a.rn = a.rn+1` to link one record to another, but this ignores locations that have moved multiple times.

The end goal is to add a column `MEETSREQ` which will be a `bit` with a 1 indicating that the location had a coordinate change and address change and these changes occurred within 1 year of each other.

Output would look something like this

```
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
| LOCATIONID | XCOORDHANGE | YCOORDCHANGE | ADDRESSCHANGE | REPORTPERIOD        | MEETREQ |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
| 1          | 0           | 0            | 1             | 2010-01-31 00:00:00 | 1       |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
| 2          | 1           | 1            | 1             | 2010-03-31 00:00:00 | 1       |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
| 1          | 1           | 1            | 0             | 2010-08-31 00:00:00 | 0       |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
| 3          | 0           | 0            | 1             | 2011-02-28 00:00:00 | 0       |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
| 4          | 1           | 1            | 0             | 2011-03-31 00:00:00 | 0       |
+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
```

This is SQL Server 2008 R2.  Thanks for your time, I hope I have added enough clarity.  I can provide additional details if necessary.

Comment: Do you require the output to still be multiple records by date of location?

Comment: Ideally the output would still be all records with the `MEETREQ` flag set to 1 on the earliest date of a confirmed move.

Comment: A cursor or stored procedure with a temp table filled by multiple queries would probably be easiest if that's available to you. I also find it easier to manage when you've got complex business logic to implement.

Comment: Yeah I had toyed with the idea of a cursor but have been told that it is bad sql, so I wasn't sure if I should implement it.  If you could expand on the idea a little I would appreciate it, I am not opposed to that route, both are available.

Comment: Cursors can be over used and don't have the best performance, but they aren't evil - they have a purpose. They can be really useful, especially if you want to do row by row logic. The temp table approach would probably be a faster approach. How many rows are there in the table and how often is this query run?

Comment: This is a one-time pull I am looking at, it won't be run very often in the future.  There are 2179 rows in the locations table (corresponding to the first table I posted), so it's not huge.

Comment: Can I confirm if MeetsReq will be 1 as long as address changes? Because LocationID 1 have it.

Comment: If the address changes and there is also an x or y coordinate change within 1 year of the address change.  An address change alone won't suffice (for example sometimes in the address AVE will get updated to AVENUE and that will be flagged as an address change but it is not a move.  Also BLVD will be changed to BLVD. which also gets the ADDRESSCHANGE flag to 1).  So LocationID 1 above has MEETREQ set to 1 on the earliest record, but the x and y change happens in August 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. Note although it's an "evil" cursor. I personally feel when you're performing complex business logic, it keeps things clear.

```
DECLARE @LOCATIONID INT
DECLARE @XCOORDHANGE INT
DECLARE @YCOORDCHANGE INT
DECLARE @ADDRESSCHANGE INT
DECLARE @REPORTPERIOD DATETIME


CREATE TABLE #Temp1 ( LOCATIONID INT, HASMOVED BIT );

-- find all locations that have an address change
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT LOCATIONID, XCOORDHANGE, YCOORDCHANGE, ADDRESSCHANGE, REPORTPERIOD 
FROM [TABLENAME]
WHERE ADDRESSCHANGE = 1

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @LOCATIONID, @XCOORDHANGE, @YCOORDCHANGE, @ADDRESSCHANGE, @REPORTPERIOD 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

    -- find any other occurance of this location within the previous year, excluding any we've already looked at
    -- and must have an x or y coord change
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM [TABLENAME] WHERE LOCATIONID = @LOCATIONID 
        AND LOCATIONID NOT IN(SELECT LOCATIONID FROM #Temp1)
        AND (XCOORDHANGE = 1 OR YCOORDCHANGE = 1)
        AND REPORTPERIOD > DATEADD(year, 1, @REPORTPERIOD)
    )
        INSERT INTO #Temp1 (LOCATIONID, HASMOVED) VALUES (@LOCATIONID, 1)
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO #Temp1 (LOCATIONID, HASMOVED) VALUES (@LOCATIONID, 0)

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @LOCATIONID, @XCOORDHANGE, @YCOORDCHANGE, @ADDRESSCHANGE, @REPORTPERIOD    
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

SELECT LOCATIONID, HASMOVED FROM #Temp1
```

You could join on your existing [TABLENAME] at the end if you like which would give you the existing table including the HasMoved column.

This may not be the exact logic you specify but it should give you the general idea of my suggested approach.

Comment: I did have to shift around the logic a bit but it seems to be working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only concerned if (x or y) and address is not 0 for a period, I used `SUM` on them in the inner query

```
SELECT  LocationID
       ,SUM(Xcoord) AS x
       ,SUM(Ycoord) AS y
       ,SUM(Address) AS a
FROM myTable
WHERE Period BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31'
GROUP BY LocationID
```

Then included a column using `CASE` on an outer query

```
SELECT  LocationID
       ,(CASE WHEN (x > 0 OR y > 0) AND a > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MeetsReq
FROM (
    SELECT  LocationID
           ,SUM(Xcoord) AS x
           ,SUM(Ycoord) AS y
           ,SUM(Address) AS a
    FROM myTable
    WHERE Period BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31'
    GROUP BY LocationID
) AS isrc
```

Then Select from your base table, left joined to the sub-query
Change NULL value of MeetsReq to 0

```
/* This is the final query. 
   The 2 queries above are included here, 
   and was just separated for explanation purposes */

SELECT main.*, COALESCE(src.MeetsReq, 0) AS MeetsReq
FROM myTable AS main
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT  LocationID
           ,(CASE WHEN (x > 0 OR y > 0) AND a > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MeetsReq
    FROM (
        SELECT  LocationID
               ,SUM(Xcoord) AS x
               ,SUM(Ycoord) AS y
               ,SUM(Address) AS a
        FROM myTable
        WHERE Period BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31'
        GROUP BY LocationID
    ) AS isrc
) AS src ON main.LocationID = src.LocationID
```

Though if a location is tagged as 1 on MeetsReq, it will be the same for all records of that location.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would do this with `LEAD()`.

```
select t.*,
       (case when lead(addresschange) over (partition by locationid order by order by reportperiod) <> addresschange and
                  (lead(xcoordchange) over (partition by locationid order by reportperiod) <> xcoordchange or
                   lead(ycoordchange) over (partition by locationid order by reportperiod) <> ycoordchange
                  )
              then 0
              else 1
        end) as meetreq
from t;
```

In earlier versions, you can do this use `outer apply`:

```
select t.*
       (case when tnext.addresschange <> addresschange and
                  (tnext.xcoordchange <> xcoordchange or
                   tnext.ycoordchange <> ycoordchange
                  )
              then 0
              else 1
        end) as meetreq
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.locationid = t.locationid and t2.reportperiod > t.reportperiod
      order by t2.reportperiod asc
     ) tnext;
```